# show text over images using jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css

I implemented the easySlider as here http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html
and now i want to show some text over the image like this http://themeforest.net/item/community-innovation/full_screen_preview/101572

I see that both are different plugins but i want to use the easySlider plugin and show the text. I tried some things like getting the alt text and displaying it over the image but din't work. any ideas please?

regards

Comment: Why don't you use a slider that already provides slides with hovering texts? Like [WOW Slider](http://www.wowslider.com/) for example.

Comment: WOOOOW that IS a slider! nice link! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the text to an element after each image, like this:

```
<li>
  <img src="[whatever]"/>
  <div>Here comes my text</div>
</li>
```

Then position with CSS by giving setting the `<li>`'s `position` property to `relative`, and `absolute` for the `<div>` that holds your text, with `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` properties, depending on your design.

```
#slider li { position: relative; }
#slider div { left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; position: absolute; }
```

Note: If you want IE6 support, use the `left`/`right`+`width` property for the `<div>` in your CSS instead of `left`+`right`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<li>` you can use `<p>` and `<span>` for the text so the code will be:

```
<p><img src=""/><span>Here the text</span></p>
```

This way the code will be valid :)